# IIS creating two instances of code running in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web

When you run your website from Visual Studio in debug mode, a browser will open "localhost:55471" and IIS express will host the site on your local machine.  If you open a second browser and navigate to the same address "localhost:55471" will IIS express create a second instance of the code running in Visual Studio (kind of like how a regular IIS runs on the server) or will it use the same instance and not create the second instance resulting in only one session for both browsers?

Comment: Second instance of what, exactly?

Comment: second instance of the code that Visual Studio is compiling for the first browser.

Comment: Code doesn't have instances.  Do you mean instances of specific classes? A new AppDomain?

Comment: yes, a new instance of the application domain.

Comment: Why don't you just print out a session variable and see?

Answer (score 0):

Both IIS and IIS Express will serve all requests from the same AppDomain.

Note, however, that this AppDomain can be recycled at any time.

Comment: IIS will serve a new instance of the AppDomain, right?

Comment: No; it will not.